# NSXMLParser parse method memory leak

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management, memory-leaks, nsxmlparser

I dont know why this `NSXMLParser parse` method is leaking.
I looked at the other similar SO question, but couldn't resolved it.

Here is my code.

```
 - (void)parseXMLFileAtURL {
self.results = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSURL *xmlURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.dukascopy.com/swiss/video/rss/"];
    NSData *dataXml = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:xmlURL];
NSXMLParser *MyrssParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:dataXml];
[dataXml release];

[MyrssParser setDelegate:self];


[MyrssParser setShouldProcessNamespaces:NO];
[MyrssParser setShouldReportNamespacePrefixes:NO];
[MyrssParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];

[MyrssParser parse]; // memory leak here
MyrssParser.delegate=nil;
[MyrssParser release];
if(!imagesArray)
{
    imagesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[self.results count]];
    for(int i=0;i<[results count];i++)
    {
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"nophoto.png"];
        [imagesArray addObject:image];
        bImgExist[i] = NO;
    }
}

  }
```

Even After releasing my NSXMLParser object instrument still shows memory leak.
What I am missing here..

Comment: Run the analyzer, by going to the Xcode menu, and selecting Product->Analyze. Post the results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
self.results = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Properties take ownership (according to their declarations) of their assigned values. So the array you set this property to is retained by `self` (I'm assuming the property is either `retain` or `copy` here), but already has a retain count of +1 from its initialization.

Change the line to:

```
self.results = [NSMutableArray array];
```

And the memory leak should clear up.

Comment: That's the only memory leak in your code sample. Any other leak must come from other code.

Comment: You are also leaking `imagesArray` if you are not releasing it in the `dealloc` method

Comment: what i am doing is that just calling that function i.e. `[self parseXMLFileAtURL]`. It jst freaking me out..:(